# If the deficiency of a presentation $P$ is $0$ and $P$ is aspherical, then the deficiency of the group $P$ defines is $0$.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I need a reference for the following theorem:

> If the deficiency of a presentation $P$ is $0$ and $P$ is aspherical, then the deficiency of the group $P$ defines is also $0$.

I think it's by Trotter but I haven't found a paper on it.

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following article might serve as a reference:

Epstein, D. B. A.
Finite presentations of groups and 3-manifolds. 
Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2) 12 1961 205–212.

Here is a proof of the statement that $d(G) = d(P)$ when the presentation 2-complex $X$ of $P$ is aspherical and $G$ is isomorphic to the group defined by the finite presentation $P$.

Lemma 1.2 of the article cited says that for any finite presentation $P$ of $G$, we have that

$$d(P) \leq {\rm rank \,} H_1(G;\mathbb{Z}) - s(H_2(G;\mathbb{Z})),$$

where for a group $A$, $s(A)$ is the minimal number of generators.

Now consider any finite presentation $P$ of $G$ and $Q$ a finite presentation of $G$ with an aspherical presentation 2-complex $X$.  The homology of $G$ is that of $X$.  Since $X$ is 2-dimensional, $H_2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is free abelian and so $s(H_2(G;\mathbb{Z}) = {\rm rank \,}H_2(G;\mathbb{Z})$.  Thus, Epstein's bound becomes

$$d(P) \leq 1 - \chi(X) = d(Q).$$

Therefore, $d(Q)$ has maximal deficiency among all finite presentations for $G$.  Notice that we do not need to assume that the deficiency is zero.

Comment: I need the *presentation* to be aspherical, not some $2$ complex.

Comment: I was not familiar with the term "aspherical presentation" and assumed it was the same.  However, I found this article (http://www.ams.org/journals/era/1998-04-15/S1079-6762-98-00052-3/S1079-6762-98-00052-3.pdf) by S. V. Ivanov which states on the second page that it was shown in the article (M. Gutierrez and J.G. Ratcliffe, On the second homotopy group, Quart. J. Math. Oxford
32 (1981)) that a presentation is aspherical if and only if the presentation 2-complex is aspherical.